# how to keep element from scrolling into view?

Tags: css

I'm using jstree plugin altogether with filament group buttons on the web page.
I would like filament group buttons to scroll out of view (stay where they are) when user scroll down but instead buttons staying in view. And that happens only on IE.
Here is how it looks when there is no scrolling:

[Before Scrolling http://i375.photobucket.com/albums/oo194/cyberkrul/temp/PositionWithScrollProblem1.png](http://i375.photobucket.com/albums/oo194/cyberkrul/temp/PositionWithScrollProblem1.png)

Now when user starts to scroll...

[When user starts scrolling ... http://i375.photobucket.com/albums/oo194/cyberkrul/temp/PositionWithScrollProblem2.png?t=1256234917](http://i375.photobucket.com/albums/oo194/cyberkrul/temp/PositionWithScrollProblem2.png?t=1256234917)

Can anybody suggest what might be the problem?

Here is html:

```
   <div id="divItems" style="overflow: auto; height: 100%;">
      <div class="fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
         <div id="divTreeToolbar" class="fg-buttonset ui-helper-clearfix">
            <a id="btnRefreshTree" href="#" class="fg-button ui-state-default fg-button-icon-solo ui-corner-all" title="Refresh"><span
               class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span>Refresh</a>
            <a id="btnSortTreeFoldersAsc" href="#" class="fg-button ui-state-default fg-button-icon-solo ui-corner-all" title="Sort Folders Ascending">
               <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"></span>Sort Asc</a>
            <a id="btnSortTreeFoldersDesc" href="#" class="fg-button ui-state-default fg-button-icon-solo ui-corner-all" title="Sort Folders Descending">
               <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-n"></span>Sort Desc</a>
            <a id="btnSearchTree" href="#" class="fg-button ui-state-default fg-button-icon-left ui-corner-all" title="Search"><span
               class="ui-icon ui-icon-search ui-icon-refresh"></span>Search</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems by the look of that scrollbar that you mean IE6.

If so, there is a bug in IE6 that causes anything with `position:absolute;` on an html page with `height:100%` to act as `position:fixed` instead.

Here is a writeup on it: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html

Comment: it definitely has something to do with container height, I removed 100% height on divItems container and buttons stay in menu tool bar.
But I've lost scroll :-(, I mean tree will expand vertically indefinitely

Comment: Can you use a fixed pixel height instead of a 100%? With jquery you could just set the height to `$(window).height()` and it would have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I know for that but I don't want to maintain dynamic height. I have solved the problem (As far as my testing shows) by enclosing tree control into separate div (treeContainer). That helped. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a problem with the positioning (duh :)). How do the code look like? 
Where are the buttons placed within the page? I think for it to be correct, the buttons should have position: absolute or position:relative, and their parent, which should be the div with the folders or some other div within that one (the one that is scrolling), also need to have position:relative so that the buttons know which div to follow.

Seeing that the background of the buttons follow the scrolling, first thing to try would be to set that one to position:relative.

I hope I made myself somewhat clear, in a bit of a hurry, but hopefully it will give you some idea of what to look for.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, I will let you know how it goes